# DENSE_RANK() - What's wrong here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a very simple table as follows:

```
ID  NAME PRICE
1   A   10.45
2   B   8.25
3   A   10.45
4   C   5.00
5   D   4.00
6   E   10.45
```

When running the `DENSE_RANK()`

```
select [name], [price], 
       DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY [name], [price] ORDER BY [name],[price]) as drank
  from temp
```

I get the below.  I was hoping to see that the second row should have `drank` of 2

```
name price  drank
A   10.45   1
A   10.45   1  //this should be 2, isn't
B   8.25    1
C   5.00    1
D   4.00    1
E   10.45   1
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are partitioning and ordering on the same columns, you've done wrong. The partition clause is the grouping, and the order the ordering. If 2 are the same, then the order, within said groups, is completely arbitrary. Also, the second row, for `NAME` `A` *should* be `1`, you asked for the [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql); ranking functions give values of equality the same rank (see [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql#remarks)). Seems like you want `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @Larnu - You are spot on.  When I changed `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY id` it gave me what I wanted.  Looks like my understanding of `dense_rank()` is incorrect.  Can you post yours as an answer?

Comment: Without knowing what the actual results you are after, I would rather not. You only tell us that the second row is wrong, but what about the other rows? What happens if `B` has 2 rows with different prices? What if `C` has 3 rows, 2 with the same value for `price` and another with a different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your misunderstanding of ranking functions. From [DENSE_RANK (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> ### Remarks
>
> If two or more rows have the same rank value in the same partition, each of those rows will receive the same rank.

The same is true for `RANK`. This means that, for your data, as both `name` and `price` have the same values, they are given the same rank; in this case `1`. *The difference between the 2 functions is how they handle rows after equal rows. `DENSE_RANK` will increment sequentially for each "new" rank, where as `RANK` will skip rankings where there are rows with equality. I.e. 1,1,2,3 and, 1,1,3,4 respectively.*

What you clearly want here, however is `ROW_NUMBER`. I do note, however, that partitioning and ordering by the same columns normally is a flaw as well, as what ever row is numbered first is arbitrary, and that arbitrary numbering might not be the same each time. Ideally you should be ordering by another column that provides an explicit order; perhaps an ID:

```sql
SELECT name,
       price,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, price ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn) AS RN
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If you don't have a column to order by, you can use an arbitrary value, or even `(SELECT NULL)` as Gordon has done in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enumerate the rows with unique numbers, use `row_number()`:

```
select [name], [price], 
       row_number() over (PARTITION BY [name], [price] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as drank
from temp;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon.  `row_number()` do work. But I really want to know why `dense_rank()` is not doing what it is supposed do.  I have kind of stripped out unnecessary details. That is, I may need to reset that column for each unique partitions.

Comment: That's a sweet technique `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`